# Tomcat SSL and keystores

Tags: java, ssl, tomcat7

I am trying to set up SSL in tomcat following the official documentation. I have some questions related to keystores involved this set up. There is a keystore at JRE/lib/security/cacerts and one configured in tomcat server.xml's connector element. Is my following assumption correct.

keystore configured in server.xml is only used for ssl connections and JRE/lib/security/cacerts is still used to trust connections made from server side code such as B2B webservice calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is correct. To be more specific, the KeyStore configured in server.xml is used for *inbound* SSL connections.